# Как определить родителя и записать в поле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую [эту](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) библиотеку для создания меню путём перетягивания элементов, как на картинке: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот как выглядит код без вложенности:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="18">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[18][name]" type="text" value="dwq">
                        <input name="page[18][order]" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <input name="page[18][parent]" type="hidden">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="19">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[19][name]" type="text" value="zxcsasa">
                        <input name="page[19][order]" type="hidden" value="2">
                        <input name="page[19][parent]" type="hidden">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="20">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[20][name]" type="text" value="ccew">
                        <input name="page[20][order]" type="hidden" value="3">
                        <input name="page[20][parent]" type="hidden">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

А вот со вложенностью:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="18"><button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[18][name]" type="text" value="dwq">
                        <input name="page[18][order]" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <input name="page[18][parent]" type="hidden">
                    </div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="19">
                            <div class="dd-handle">
                                <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[19][name]" type="text" value="zxcsasa">
                                <input name="page[19][order]" type="hidden" value="2">
                                <input name="page[19][parent]" type="hidden">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="20">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input class="form-control" required="" disabled="" name="page[20][name]" type="text" value="ccew">
                        <input name="page[20][order]" type="hidden" value="3">
                        <input name="page[20][parent]" type="hidden">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Comment: дак событие `change` же вроде заявлено - используйте.